# Convert entire data row into column header in SQL or using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, unpivot

I have a table that is created dynamically from excel and a sample looks like this

```
F1     F2     F3     F4    F5
ColA   ColB   ColC   Week1 Week2
1      Mango  Fruit  5     6
2      Potato Veg    4     3
3      Grapes Fruit  4     4
```

In the above example, `F1`, `F2` are the columns of the table. However `ColA`, `ColB` are the actual column headers of the data and `Week1`, `Week2` keep changing

I need the above data converted into the format below :

```
ColA   ColB     ColC       Week      Qty
1      Mango    Fruit      Week1     5
1      Mango    Fruit      Week2     6
2      Potato   Veg        Week1     4
2      Potato   Veg        Week2     3
3      Grapes   Fruit      Week1     4
3      Grapes   Fruit      Week2     4
```

I generated a unique ID for every Row in my staging table and identified the header and data rows separately. Then I tried to use unpivot in SQL and SSIS and even dynamic SQL. However I'm unable to get the desired output and I'm stuck. Can anyone out there guide me on an approach so that I can take it further to implement a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a stored procedure making use of a cursor to iterate through the columns of my first staging table and created another transformed table. This table has actual column headers which were present as data row in my former staging table.

Then i used SQL unpivot to transpose my data.

Thanks @Prabhat G for your analysis on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Unpivot` shouldn't be a problem atleast. Try this:

```
create table tbl(F1 varchar(20),F2 varchar(20),F3 varchar(20),F4 varchar(20),F5 varchar(20))
insert into tbl values
('ColA','ColB','ColC','Week1','Week2'),
('1','Mango'  ,'Fruit','5','6'),
('2','Potato' ,'Veg','4','3'),
('3','Grapes' ,'Fruit','4','4')


SELECT F1 as ColA, F2 as ColB, F3 as ColC,week_no, quantity 
FROM
    (SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
     FROM tbl) iq
    UNPIVOT
    (quantity FOR Week_no IN(F4, F5)
    ) As wk1
WHERE F1 not in ('ColA')  //to filter out header
```

output:

```
ColA   ColB       ColC        week_no    quantity
-----  -------    -------     --------   -----------
1      Mango      Fruit       week1      5
1      Mango      Fruit       week2      6
2      Potato     Veg         week1      4
2      Potato     Veg         week2      3
3      Grapes     Fruit       week1      4
3      Grapes     Fruit       week2      4
```

Comment: Let me try and I shall let you know how it went

Comment: My challenge is the Col A ColB ColC is a row in my staging table and columns after Col C ie Week 1, Week2 will change dynamically as we roll into a new work week. The actual columns of the table are F1,F2,F3..etc

Comment: To skip header in staging, look into ssis source connection or oledb source properties. It is there. I'll find it out as well on Monday. There is an option to define and skip header rows. For dynamic unpivot, just google it. You'll come across many links. Then you just need to modify it based on my above answer.

Comment: ok let me try and I shall update the outcome. Thanks for look into this. much appreciated!!

Comment: Im not aware of any OLE db properties where u can ignore column headers. My challenge is Im unable to construct an unpivot as my actual column header is a row along with other data rows. I have been struggling around this for a long time now and still trying

Comment: @Mekha : I ll put up a way for SSIS method. Meanwhile, I've updated answer. Check it out. It is exactly as per your sample data. I've used `Where` to filter out header. Will it work if we make this query dynamic? This will solve your header issue.